# Unity Application.LoadLevel freezes the game on Android device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game using Unity. The game has a single level and after the player wins/loses, I simply want to reload the same scene. Here's the code I'm using:

```
private void OnLevelFailed()
{
    IsGameStarted = false;
    Debug.Log("LEVEL FAILED");
    Invoke("RestartLevel",5);
}

void RestartLevel()
{
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevelName);
}
```

When running this code on the editor, everything seems fine and the scene reloads as intended. However, when I build the game for Android and run it on a device (an LG G3), the game simply freezes. I used `adb logcat` to see the logs of any exceptions or errors if there were any but to no luck. I also suspected if the `Invoke` call was causing the problem and replaced it with simply the method call, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Anyone have any idea why this might happen?

EDIT: It seems like the problem is caused by a prefab I'm using, namely [ALPSVR](http://www.alpsvr.com/). It is a virtual reality SDK that allows you to have VR cameras independent of Unity's own VR implementation (which supports some VR devices and GearVR, but not regular Android devices).

I tried destroying the VR camera from the scene before reloading it but again it didn't solve the problem. Why would a certain GameObject inside a scene prevent Application.LoadLevel from working properly?

Comment: is your Time.timeScale = 0 ?

Comment: If you are using Unit 4.x, you need Unity Pro otherwise ALPSVR will not work.

Comment: @JeanLuc, I haven't touched the timeScale in anywhere inside the game. Would that cause a problem though?

Comment: @Puneet I'm using Unity 5.1.

Comment: yes if with a timeScale of 0 the 5 seconds would actually never pass and you method `RestartLevel`  not invoked

Comment: @JeanLuc Hmm, yeah I never thought of that, thanks. Though as I said, I haven't touched the timeScale anywhere inside the game.

Comment: Does the game fail to load at all after Unity splashscreen or does it freeze after invoke is called?

Answer (score 0):

You may have success using `Application.LoadLevelAsync(Application.loadedLevelName);`.

If that does not work, consider creating a second blank scene. When your game level is completed, call `Application.LoadLevel(Application.blankScene);`, then have this script on a GameObject in that blank scene:

```
public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
    {
      void Start()
      {
        StartCoroutine(ReloadLevel());
      }

      IEnumerator ReloadLevel()
      {
        yield return Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevelName);
      }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It seems that I also can't load any other scene. However, if I start with another scene and use your code to load my main scene, it works. There must be something wrong in my main scene but I have no idea what.

Comment: If you start with that blank scene and then load your main scene, does it still work after your level ends and you go blank > main scene again? If so, that might actually be a suitable solution. Generally you'd be doing this anyway because you need a menu scene. So go Menu > Main > Blank > Main > Blank > Main, etc.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. I can't navigate from the main scene to any other scene. You can see my edit above for further info I discovered about the problem.